# Java split(), use whole word containing a specific character as separator

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String string = "3 5 3 -4 2 3 ";
```

I want to use `split()` here but I need to a separator to be `-4`. I don't know which numbers are negative and I need to use split to group positive numbers in separate arrays.

Is it possible?

Edit:

I want to use:

```
String[] parts = string.split(????);
```

and receive

```
parts[0] = "3 5 3"
parts[1] = "2 3"
```

Comment: What is `slice()`?

Comment: I meant `split` of course

Comment: If you split on space it shouldn't matter... then you can sort or use stream and filter to group the items by condition (negative/positive etc)

Comment: What is the expected result in your example?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, see edit now

Comment: `for (String retval: Str.split("-\\d+")){
         System.out.println(retval);
      }`

Comment: `Arrays.stream(string.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).filter(i -> i > -1).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: see **[here](http://ideone.com/BQkpOJ)**

Comment: see [**here**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMkdRU0t4blJZaFU) :P

Comment: Thank you all, I used rock's answer and it works perfectly. \d+ was what I needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I mentioned in comments, you can use `-\\d+` for splitting.
It finds all the places where there is `-` followed by any number of digits. We can trim the array elements later if we want

*Java Code*

```
String Str = new String("3 5 3 -4 2 3");
String[] x = Str.split("-\\d+");

for (String retval: x){
   System.out.println(retval.trim());
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/BQkpOJ)**

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `replace` method to search for a given string (in this case, -4) and replace it with a delimiter of your choice, perhaps a pipe-bar line (`|`). Then you can use the split method and use the delimiter that's now inserted to split your array.

```
string = string.replace(replaceString, "|");
string[] parts = string.split('|');
```

Admittedly this is a little roundabout, but it's quick, easy, and will work.

Answer (score 0):

Using StringUtils you can do something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String splitMe="123-457";
    String [] newArray=StringUtils.split(splitMe, "-4");


    for (String val:newArray){
        System.out.println(val.toString());
    }
}
```

output will be 123 for 1st index and 57 for second index

Comment: I downvoted because your answer is only working for the *example* that the user provided. I don't think that the question was only about the specific string. Otherwise, it would be faster to create two arrays manually, one with "123" and the other with "57"... Also, I don't see the need to use StringUtils instead of String's split even in that case.

Comment: @vefthym He's demonstrating how StringUtils is used - this answer is perfectly valid. All the asker would need to do is swap out the parameters.

Comment: @JeremyKato I disagree. Please, see rock321987's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/37622489/2516301). It works for any negative number. You may have missed this part of the OP: "I don't know which numbers are negative and I need to use split to group positive numbers in separate arrays." -4 is just an example

Comment: @vefthym My sole purpose was to show how this can be done with a StringUtils split method and using  -4 as a delimiter for this example as he had posted in his question. He is only looking for a tool and this example only provides an insight with an example of -4 being used as a delimiter. He can use this example to use StringUtils split method and replace the -4 with any regular expression he intends to.